# How to Clear EclipseLink Query Results Cache from a CDI Interceptor?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, cdi, interceptor

I'm using EclipseLink's Query Results Cache:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll",
    query = "SELECT s FROM ...",
    hints= {
            @QueryHint(name=QueryHints.QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE, value=HintValues.TRUE)
            ...
```

and I first manually cleared the cache by using a  stateless bean named "CacheManager", which had the following method:

```
public void invalidateCacheForQuery(String namedQueryName) {
    log.info("CacheManagerService: clearing cache for named query " + namedQueryName);
     ((JpaCache) em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache())
         .clearQueryCache(namedQueryName);
}
```

I'd call this method whenever there was a modification (add/delete) that could've made the query results obsolete. The call was made directly after the modification, e.g.

```
em.merge(u);
cacheMan.invalidateCacheForQuery("..."); // for each cached query
```

(I'm cutting corners here a bit, this is the essence of what I was doing).

The above solution worked well - I have JUnit tests that will fail if the cache is not cleared, and they do not fail if the above "invalidateCacheForQuery" calls are present (and do fail if they are not).

Then I tried to make my life easier by defining an interceptor:

```
@EJB CacheManager cacheMan;

@AroundInvoke
public Object clearQueryCacheAfterwards(InvocationContext ctx)
        throws Exception {

    // this does something like em.persist that might make cached query results
    // invalid:
    final Object result = ctx.proceed(); 

    // hera are calls cacheMan.invalidateCacheForQuery for all of the relevant named
    // queries. Yes, this is done after ctx.proceed().

    return result;
}
```

Note: I kept the code above terse: The interceptor annotation accepted a Class object as its parameter, and I used the class object to find all its NamedQueries' names that had a QueryHint indicating that they were cached. This is just to explain how I found what named queries to clear.

The Interceptor approach does not work, and I have no idea why. **I know the method `invalidateCacheForQuery(String namedQueryName)` gets called also with the Interceptor approach (with the right named query names) as I get the correct log messages.** I also get log messages form the interceptor. Therfore the Interceptor mechanism is working, e.g. it is not a simple problem like definition missing from beans.xml. However, I know cache clearing does not work because my JUnit tests fail the same way they fail if I did not clear the cache at all.

Looking at the log, these consecutive lines make me sure the interceptor is doing what it should:

```
ClearQueryCacheInterceptor: clearing query cache for named query User.findAll 
CacheManagerService: clearing cache for named query User.findAll
```

I also tried to use `@PersistenceContext(unitName="...") EntiytyManager em;` in the interceptor and clear the cache through that without using the CacheManager EJB.

So to recap the lenghty explanation: I have two approaches calling the same method that invalidates EclipseLink's query result cache. I have verified through logging that both approaches manage to call that method with the same parameters (NamedQuery names). The inline "after em.persist()" way works, but doing essentially exactly the same thing in interceptor does not. It kind of feels like I'm clearing another instance of EclipseLink's cache with the interceptor, but I don't know how that'd be possible.

Comment: Is your EJB stateless or stateful?

Comment: Everything's stateless.

Comment: Could be you're clearing a different instance of the session bean.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are working on two different PersistenceContexts when using the Interceptor approach.

Looks like your interceptor configuration is working on the Entity level, which is not sharing the PersistenceContext of your EJB container. Try to move the interceptor to your service layer (apply it to the EJBs that persist/modify the data). It's not so automatic as your are trying to do, but should work.